# Set source and target in d3 javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I've been following Mike Bostock's code: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022 to learn how to draw graphs in d3. He has in links variable assigned all the sources and targets 'by hand'. I was wondering how can I draw this with my own source and targets.

In my application, I only have one source 'submitter', and more targets 'author' (author is an array with 5 values). All I am trying to do is to draw a graph with 6 nodes: one root and 5 children.

This is what I've tried by now, but it's not working. I only have 2 nodes: the submitter and the first author form the array.

```
var links = [
            {
                source: submitter,
                target: function () {
                    for (var j = 1; j < json.length; j++) {
                        return author[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        ];
```

Any ideas how can I resolve this?

Comment: Why don't you do the other way around? https://jsfiddle.net/6chfdcvk/

Comment: Wow, didn't think about that! I am still new to this, thank you very much!!!